# ClickOnce application

Tags: project, clickonce, installation, publishing

I have prepared a ClickOnce application. All my files and a folder in the same location includes application files (folder), connexionDeployment_V2.application, connexionsetup.msi (my setup to call in default.htm), default.htm (to setup the application), setup.exe (redundant).

`Default.htm` includes a command line that is

```
<a href="./connexionsetup.msi"> run application </a>
```

After finishing project, my ClickOnce project does not behave like a ClickOnce project. That is, it is not doing the setup process by itself; it is doing the setup process normal setup application by waiting for my click "next-next-next", but a ClickOnce application, as you know, begins the setup process by itself and it does not look like a normal download project and it does not tell me to click next click next to continue because it does all steps by itself.

How can I fix this problem? How can my application behave like an original ClickOnce application?

**Pictures of my steps**

My command line:

[image]

After clicking run application:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your link is trying to install using an msi which is not the ClickOnce application you are looking for. ClickOnce.

connexionDeployment_V2.application is used to run the application if all prerequisites are installed.

setup.exe is use to install the application if you do not have prerequisites installed.

msi is usually a standalone installer like you are seeing.

Why not use the default generated page for ClickOnce publishing? How are you creating the ClickOnce deployment?

Comment: How should I create clickonce deployment and how will it create a default page? Can you help me?

Comment: In fact, I create a windows form application, then I create virtual site (localhost) on the IIS, then I create a default.htm in folder in IIS, I place the a different setup which is named "connexionsetup.msi", I write a code line like "<a href="./connexionsetup.msi"> run application </a>". setup.exe is setup application of my windows form application, but I did not use such setup.exe because I want to call a different setup application named "connexionsetup.msi" which is ready to run and in the same index with default.htm

Comment: Ok but connectionsetup.msi is not ClickOnce so you will not get a ClickOnce setup or install a ClickOnce application. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e2444w33.aspx. If you use Visual Studio it is very easy to create and deploy ClickOnce including to IIS.